# What is the difference between i++ & ++i in a for loop?

Tags: java, increment

I've just started learning Java and now I'm into for loop statements. I don't understand how `++i` and `i++` works in a for-loop.

How do they work in mathematics operations like addition and subtraction?

Comment: Many existing instances. Short answer: for native types nothing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484462/difference-between-i-and-i-in-a-loop http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941391/java-to-i-or-i-and-whats-the-difference-closed and many others taken from http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=i%2B%2B+%2B%2Bi

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756015/whats-the-difference-between-i-and-i-in-php

Comment: ++i should be more efficient in theory since i++ simply a ++i and a copy ( to save the earlier value )
But i guess JVM will optimize the latter in a for loop (atleast any compiler would do...) -> no difference

Answer (score 55):

They both increment the number. `++i` is equivalent to `i = i + 1`.

`i++` and `++i` are very similar but not exactly the same. Both increment the number, but `++i` increments the number before the current expression is evaluted, whereas `i++` increments the number after the expression is evaluated.

```
int i = 3;
int a = i++; // a = 3, i = 4
int b = ++a; // b = 4, a = 4
```

Comment: To answer the actual question, however, they're essentially identical within the context of typical `for` loop usage.

Comment: Point of pedantry: `i = i + 1` is an expression with a value one more than the initial value of `i`, which would make it more like `++i`.

Answer (score 44):

Here's a sample class:

```
public class Increment
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; ++i)
        {
            System.out.println(args[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

If I disassemble this class using javap.exe I get this:

```
Compiled from "Increment.java"
public class Increment extends java.lang.Object{
public Increment();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   iconst_0
   1:   istore_1
   2:   iload_1
   3:   aload_0
   4:   arraylength
   5:   if_icmpge       23
   8:   getstatic       #2; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   11:  aload_0
   12:  iload_1
   13:  aaload
   14:  invokevirtual   #3; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   17:  iinc    1, 1
   20:  goto    2
   23:  return

}
```

If I change the loop so it uses i++ and disassemble again I get this:

```
Compiled from "Increment.java"
public class Increment extends java.lang.Object{
public Increment();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   iconst_0
   1:   istore_1
   2:   iload_1
   3:   aload_0
   4:   arraylength
   5:   if_icmpge       23
   8:   getstatic       #2; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   11:  aload_0
   12:  iload_1
   13:  aaload
   14:  invokevirtual   #3; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   17:  iinc    1, 1
   20:  goto    2
   23:  return

}
```

When I compare the two, TextPad tells me that the two are identical.

What this says is that from the point of view of the generated byte code there's no difference in a loop.  In other contexts there is a difference between ++i and i++, but not for loops.

Comment: +1 for going the extra mile.

Comment: It's not the loop that's doing it, it's the fact that it's not in a larger expression context.  If your loop-end expression was more complicated, it might very well make a difference.

Comment: I'll add more to the loop example and try again to see.

Comment: Absolute +1 for this answer! ... Although it can makes difference in situation like: "for (int i = 0, int j = 0; i < args.length; j += ++i)" vs. "for (int i = 0, int j = 0; i < args.length; j += i++)"

Answer (score 20):

Both of them increase the variable `i` by one. It's like saying `i = i + 1`. The difference is subtle. If you're using it in a loop like this, there's no difference:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
}

for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
}
```

If you want to know the difference, look at this example:

```
int a = 0;
int b = a++; // b = 0; a = 1

a = 0;
b = ++a: // b = 1; a = 1
```

The idea is that `++a` increments `a` and returns that value, while `a++` returns a's value and then increments `a`.

Answer (score 7):

The way for loop is processed is as follows

1 First, initialization is performed (i=0)

2 the check is performed (i < n)

3 the code in the loop is executed.

4 the value is incremented

5 Repeat steps 2 - 4

This is the reason why, there is no difference between i++ and ++i in the for loop which has been used.

Comment: This was the answer that I was looking for.  Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

The difference is that the post-increment operator `i++` returns `i` as it was *before* incrementing, and the pre-increment operator `++i` returns `i` as it is *after* incrementing.   If you're asking about a typical `for` loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

or

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
```

They're exactly the same, since you're not using `i++` or `++i` as a part of a larger expression.

Answer (score 3):

Both `i++` and `++i` are short-hand for `i = i + 1`.

In addition to changing the value of i, they also return the value of i, either before adding one (`i++`) or after adding one (`++i`).

In a loop the third component is a piece of code that is executed after each iteration.

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
```

The value of that part is not used, so the above is just the same as

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i = i+1)
```

or

```
for(int i=0; i<10; ++i)
```

Where it makes a difference (between `i++` and `++i` )is in these cases

```
while(i++ < 10)

for (int i=0; i++ < 10; )
```

Comment: See TomH's pedantry in David's answer, i=i+1 is identical to ++i, not i++ :-)

Answer (score 0):

[JLS§14.14.1, *The basic for Statement*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.14.1), makes it clear that the *ForUpdate* expression(s) are evaluated and the value(s) are *discarded*. The effect is to make the two forms identical in the context of a `for` statement.