# What is difference between while(++i < --j) & while(i++<j--)?

Tags: java

I try this below program which find midpoint between two no.

```
class FindMidPoint

{

public static void main(String args[])

{

int i, j;

i = 100;

j = 200;


// find midpoint between i and j

while(++i < --j) ;

System.out.println("Midpoint is " + i+" OR "+j);

}

}
```

Output:

```
Midpoint is 150 OR 150

But If I make changing in while condition that is

while(i++<j--)

Then output is:

Midpoint is 16 OR 14
```

I also refer the below Link then also I'm not understanding the difference between ++i & i++ in this program.

[what is the difference between i++ & ++i in for loop (Java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315705/what-is-the-difference-between-i-i-in-for-loop-java)

Please explain me if anyone have idea about.

Comment: The output is not `Midpoint is 16 OR 14`. Please can you check again.

Comment: You are basically asking the difference between pre-increment and post-increment, and pre-decrement and post-decrement.

Comment: Consider increasing the line spacing in your editor so you don't have to put an empty line between each line of code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have i = 1 and j = 2. The first one compares 2 < 1 and the second one compares 1 < 2. (In the first one the decrementation/incrementation are done before the comparing, while in the second one they are done after the comparison)

Answer (score 0):

The `++` before any variable present in an expression indicates that increment has to be made before the expression executes.

For example

```
int i=2;
int x = ++i + 2
```

Here since `++` is present before i, so first there will be an increment on **i**, and then the expression will be executed.
The steps involved is :

Step 1 :

```
++i : i=(i+1) = 3
```

Step2:

```
int x = ++i + 2 = 3+2=5
```

So after this expression executes : **x=5 and i=3**

But if you consider post increment:

For example:

```
 int i=2;
 int x = i++ + 2;
```

This means that increment will happen after the line is executed.
The steps are:

Step 1 :

```
int x = i++ + 2 = 2 + 2 =4; // i is still 2 here since the increment didn't happen by now
```

Step 2:

```
i++ : i=i+1 = 3;
```

So after the execution **x=4 and i=3**

Answer (score 0):

```
++i
```

You could think something like increment the value and then use the incremented value in the expression

```
i++
```

Use the value in the expression before it gets incremented

Say we have the following code:

```
int i = 100;
int j = ++i + 50;  // statement 1
```

Here `j` would have a value of 151, saying increment `i` first and then evaluate the expression, so 101+50.

Lets way we have

```
int j = i++ + 50;  // statement 2
```

Here `j` would have a value of 150, saying evaluate the expression first, then increment the value `i`

However, `i` would be 101 after executing the second statement

Answer (score 0):

Its all about precedence, in java every operator has a precedence, **pre-increment** has very high precedence while **post-increment** come at last as compared to other operators.

Answer (score 0):

Basic difference between pre and post should be applied here.

Pre increment operator ++i : equivalent to replacing i with i+1 and using result in the expression.

```
while(++i < --j);
//read as while( (i_new = i_old+1) < (j_new =j_old -1) );
//In next expression i will be value of i_new and j value will be j_new
```

Post increment operator i++ : equivalent to using the same value of i in the current expression. And in the next immediate expression use the increased value.

```
while(i++ < j--);
//read as while( (i_old < j_old );
//In next expression(even in next iteration of same above while) i will be value of i_old+1 and j value will be j_old-1
```