# How to add a comma at the end of every element in Array

Tags: java, android, arraylist

In my application I want use this [Library](https://github.com/adroitandroid/ChipCloud) for show `ArrayList` items.
**My ArrayList from server:**

```
"genres": [
      "Action",
      " Comedy",
      " Family"
    ]
```

I write below code for show Items:

```
private String[] mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings;
    private List<String> cloudChipList = new ArrayList<>();
mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings = serialResponse.getData().getGenres();
                for (String str : mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings) {
                    cloudChipList.add(str);
                    if (cloudChipList.size() > 0) {
                        infoSerialFrag_GenreChips.addChip(str);
                    }
                }
```

**show me such as this:**

> Ganre : Action Comedy Family

**But I want show me such as this :**

> Ganre : Action , Comedy , Family

Comment: Where is your display code where you show Genre

Comment: Something like [`String.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-)?

Comment: with Java 8, you can use my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50834484/2234161

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for `String.join()`

```
List<String> foo = new ArrayList<>();
foo.add("foo");
foo.add("bar");
foo.add("baz");
System.out.println(String.join(", ", foo));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either convert to a `List` and use `String.join(", ", list)`, or you can use a `StringJoiner`:

```
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(", ");
for (String s : mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings) {
    sj.add(s);
}
String joined = sj.toString();
```

Note that this requires Java 8; if you're using Java < 8, you would have to do something similar to the answer by [Professor901](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45512195/1690108).

Comment: can you edit your answer and send send to me full code with my above codes? please

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you could do the following:

```
String[] items = { "Foo", "Bar" };
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < items.length;) {
    result.append(items[i]);

    if(++i < items.length)
        result.append(", ");
}
String str = result.toString(); // "Foo, Bar"
```

It's the same for ArrayLists, but you would `list.get(i)` instead of `items[i]`:

```
ArrayList<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("Foo"); list.add("Bar");
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); ) {
    result.append(list.get(i));

    if(++i < list.size())
        result.append(", ");
}
String str = result.toString(); // "Foo, Bar"
```

Comment: Incrementing `i` in the middle of the loop (and inside the condition of an if) makes it harder to understand that it should

Comment: Yeah, but it's probably faster. You could also increment `i` at the top of the loop and use `i < items.length - 1` in the if-statement.

Comment: I don't see how it could possibly be faster than putting it at the top of the loop. Also, `i++` returns the value as it was before the incrementation so your `if` is equivalent to comparing to `i`  and **then** incrementing. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2315717/3072566

Comment: Also, i actually tested it and it does not work. An extra , is added at the end.

Comment: Change `i++` to `++i`

Comment: can you edit your answer and send send to me full code with my above codes? please

Comment: The code in my answer works as it is, i've tested it. I've added the arraylist code, so you just have to copy it and modify the variables used.