# JAVA - logic error in main method

Tags: java

I have an assignment that requires me to write a program in JAVA with 10 different methods including the main. It obtains the input from a file in order to extract data from a second file through the various methods. Lastly it prints the results to a third file. THis is an intro class and we were insturcted to use the hasNext method. THe second file where the data is retrieved from has 10 rows and 5 columns, each column representing something different. I used sc1.nextInt() since our professor warned us that the programs will read every piece of data and we havent learned how to extract data from just one column. I am stuck on an error I keep receiving. I have included a snippet of my code if anyone can help me. Thank you.

this is the error I keep receiving:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.util.InputMismatchException at
>   java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864) at
>   java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485) at
>   java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117) at
>   java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076) at
>   homework4.HomeWork4.checkNumber(HomeWork4.java:47) at
>   homework4.HomeWork4.main(HomeWork4.java:26)
>   /Users/xiomarahenriquez/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53:
>   Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)"

```
public static PrintStream ps;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ps = new PrintStream("elementsResults.txt");
    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
    int atomicNumber, valid=0, invalid=0, totalProcessed=0;

    while (sc1.hasNext()) {
        atomicNumber = sc1.nextInt();
        checkNumber(atomicNumber);

        if(checkNumber(atomicNumber)== true){
            ++valid;
        } else {
            ++invalid;
        }
        ++totalProcessed;
    }   
}

public static boolean checkNumber (int atomicNumber) throws Exception {
    Scanner sc2 = new Scanner (new File("PeriodicTable.txt"));
    int columnA = sc2.nextInt();
    String columnB;
    int columnC,columnD,columnE;

    while (sc2.hasNext() && (columnA > -1 || columnA < 118)) {    
        columnA=sc2.nextInt();
        columnB=sc2.next();
        columnC=sc2.nextInt();
        columnD=sc2.nextInt();
        columnE=sc2.nextInt();
        if (atomicNumber==columnA) {
            return true;
        }
    } 

    sc2.close();
    return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the cause of your problem is in the first line of your exception stack trace:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

Here's a link to the documentation for the [InputMismatchException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html).  I can't say for sure since I don't know what your input files look like but I'm pretty sure that when you're calling `nextInt()`, the next token read isn't something that can be cast to an `int`.  My guess is that the Scanner is encountering some text or something else preventing it from returning an `int`.  To figure out which token is causing the problem, I'd try wrapping your invocations of `nextInt()` in try/catch blocks.  When the Scanner throws an `InputMismatchException`, it will not pass the token that caused the exception so that after the exception is thrown you can get the value of the token (like with the `next()` method) or skip the token altogether.  Here's an example (I don't have access to an IDE right now so this isn't tested but hopefully you can get the idea):

```
//Some initialization code here...
Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(new File("myFile.txt"));
while(myScanner.hasNext()) {
    try {
        int myIntVariable = myScanner.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
        System.out.println("Here's the token that caused the problem: " + myScanner.next());
    }
}
//The rest of your code here...
```

By the way, if you're not absolutely sure that the token that you're retrieving is the type that you think it's going to be (in your case an `int`), it's probably a good idea to wrap that portion of the code in a try/catch block so that you can handle cases where the token isn't what you think it is.

Answer (score 1):

This is my first answer. Hope it helps.
In your while loop you are running the checkNumber method twice. That's unnecessary. Do it just once like below. Also there is a slight difference between ++i and i++ so check this link: [what is the difference between i++ & ++i in for loop (Java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315705/what-is-the-difference-between-i-i-in-for-loop-java)

```
while (sc1.hasNext()) {
    atomicNumber = sc1.nextInt();

    if(checkNumber(atomicNumber)== true){
        valid++;
    } else {
        invalid++;
    }
    totalProcessed++;
}
```