# Why does my config.yml file keep on outputting only zero? bukkit plugin

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I have made a plugin that is supposed to track the amount of diamonds you have mined in Minecraft and save it to a config.yml file. But my code doesn't seem to be working and I cant figure out why?

I've already tried +1 in the setConfig args and now I've switched over to this and it still doesn't seem to be working. I also have diamonds predefined in my config.yml file.

```
package com.raidoxe.BlockPlugin;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.PluginManager;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {


    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        getLogger().info("Sartu has been enabled :)");
        PluginManager pm = getServer().getPluginManager();
        SartuListener listener = new SartuListener(this);
        pm.registerEvents(listener, this);
        this.getConfig().options().copyDefaults(true);
        this.saveConfig();


    }

public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
        Player player = (Player) sender;

        if (sender instanceof Player) {
            String lowerCmd = cmd.getName().toLowerCase();

            switch (lowerCmd) {

            case "mydiamonds":

                int a = this.getConfig().getInt("diamonds."+player.getUniqueId());
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE+"You have mined "+ChatColor.RED+a+ChatColor.AQUA+" Diamonds");

                return true;    
            }
        }
        return true;
        }


------------Listener File-----------

package com.raidoxe.BlockPlugin;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.block.Block;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.BlockBreakEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.block.BlockPlaceEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.AsyncPlayerChatEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin;

public class SartuListener implements Listener {

    private Plugin plugin = Main.getPlugin(Main.class);
    public SartuListener(Main plugin) {

    }

    @EventHandler
    public void blockBreak(BlockBreakEvent event) {
        Player player = (Player) event.getPlayer();
        Block block = event.getBlock();
        Material blockMaterial = block.getType();
        if(blockMaterial.equals(Material.DIAMOND_ORE)) {
            Bukkit.broadcastMessage(ChatColor.WHITE+player.getDisplayName()+" found a "+ ChatColor.AQUA + ChatColor.BOLD+"Diamond!!!");
            int a = plugin.getConfig().getInt("diamonds."+player.getUniqueId());
            plugin.getConfig().set("diamonds."+player.getUniqueId(), a++);
            plugin.saveConfig();
        }

    }
```

when the player does the command /mydiamonds it should print out, "you have mined (a) diamonds". But it always prints out zero, no matter how many diamonds you have mined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be looking fine except one minor mistake. You say that you've tried +1 in the setConfig, so if this solution does not work for you it's probably a version thing

If a config `getInt()` returns 0 it can mean two things:

1. value does not exist (default is returned)
2. value is actually 0 in the config

Upon testing the value does exist in the config (due to `saveConfig()`, but is set to 0. So this lead me to the setting method.

The issue is the adding part. You do a++ inside the method, this will increment the number **after** the method, we want before, switch to ++a. [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315705/what-is-the-difference-between-i-i-in-for-loop-java).

```
if(blockMaterial.equals(Material.DIAMOND_ORE)) {
    Bukkit.broadcastMessage(ChatColor.WHITE+player.getDisplayName()+" found a "+ ChatColor.AQUA + ChatColor.BOLD+"Diamond!!!");
    int a = plugin.getConfig().getInt("diamonds."+player.getUniqueId());
    plugin.getConfig().set("diamonds."+player.getUniqueId(), ++a);
    plugin.saveConfig();
}
```