# compare elements array PHP

Tags: php

I've a problem with this code:
In the array $p i have characters and i'd like to compare the elements of the array if i find different elements i save the information in an other array called $ora, but it isnt work, what's the problem?? Thank you very mych

```
$uri = 'http://www.site.com';
$output=file_get_contents($uri);

  if (preg_match_all('/<td colspan="1"><div class="tbl_EPG_TimesColumn.*?">(.*?)<\/div><\/td>/s', $output,  $posts, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER)){

 $p=$posts[0];

   }

$count=count($p);

  $ora = array();

  for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {

    if ($p[$i] != $p[$i++]){

     $ora =  $p;

   }

    echo $ora."     "; 

}
```

EDIT:

$count=count($p);

$ora = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $count-1; $i++) {

```
 for ($j = 0; $j < $count-1; $j++) {

    if ($p[$i] != $p[$i+1]){

            $ora[$j] =  $p[$i];
     }  
  }
```

}

$count2=count($ora);

for ($j = 0; $j < $count2; $j++) {

echo $ora[$j]."     ";

}

---

i tried it but it doesnt work, what is the wrong'??

### this is the output:

11:00 PM

11:00 PM

11:00 PM

11:00 PM

11:00 PM

11:00 PM

11:00 PM

11:00 PM

### 11:00 PM

Comment: this  if ($p[$i] != $p[$i++]) will be true, it is the same is $p[$i] != $p[$i] because of the ++ placement. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756015/whats-the-difference-between-i-and-i-in-php

Comment: Should `$ora` be an array? If so then the assignment and echo statements are wrong.

Comment: you logic in the code is not clear. What are you trying to do ?

Comment: use http://de3.php.net/array_diff

Comment: print $p and show us here, that would be helpful

Comment: $count=count($p);

$ora = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $count-1; $i++) {

     for ($j = 0; $j < $count-1; $j++) {

        if ($p[$i] != $p[$i+1]){

                $ora[$j] =  $p[$i];
         }  
      }
} 

$count2=count($ora);

for ($j = 0; $j < $count2; $j++) {

echo $ora[$j]."     "; 

}

-----------------
i tried it but it doesnt work, what is the wrong'??

this is the output:
----------------------
11:00 PM

11:00 PM

11:00 PM

11:00 PM

11:00 PM

11:00 PM

11:00 PM

11:00 PM

11:00 PM
-----------------

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question.

If you want to check that every character in $p is the same you can do this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $count-1; $i++) {
    if ($p[$i] != $p[$i+1]){
        $ora = $p;
    }
    echo $ora."     "; 
}
```

Notice how $count should really be $count-1. Also make sure that $count=count($p) is $count=strlen($p)

Of course only if I understood correctly what you want to do.

EDIT: I automatically used $i+1 instead of $i++ but as the previous reply correctly states: Don't increment $i here! It will be a post increment anyway and thus absolutely unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

Well the if will never be true, as you are doing post-increment which means that this if: `$p[$i] != $p[$i++]` would be equal in meaning to `$p[$i] != $p[$i]`. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756015/whats-the-difference-between-i-and-i-in-php).
Also its not that clear about what you are trying to do. If you want to remove duplicate values from your array, you should use [array_unique](https://www.php.net/array_unique).

And be aware that $ora is array, and each time when the if will be true it'll overrite the previus value. The right way to do it is adding elements to $ora array like this: `$ora[] = 'new value';`