# PHP equation output confusion

Tags: php

```
$x = 5; echo "$x"; echo "<br>"; echo $x+++$x++; echo "<br>"; echo $x;
```

Wouldn't the output of the code above be "5,12,5"? PHP outputs "5,11,7"?

Why? I am confuse.

Comment: `$x++ + $x++` post-increment

Comment: But the original value of $x is 5. So isn't it always going to be 5 when $x is called upon?

Answer (score 1):

The first reference to $x is when its value is still 5 (i.e., before it is incremented) and the second reference to $x is then when its value is 6 (i.e., before it is again incremented), so the operation is 5 + 6 which yields 11. After this operation, the value of $x is 7 since it has been incremented twice.

So it's basically

1. Supply 5 as one of the operands to an addition operation.
2. Increment x after supplying it to addition operation (post increment), which makes it 6.
3. Supply this previous incremented x as second operand to the addition operation, which is 6. So it makes it 5+6, yields 11
4. Lastly increment x after addition operation making it 7

Comment: Sorry, wrote in hurry. Corrected

Comment: Actually it would be `$x(5)++(6)+$x(6+5 = 11)++ (7)` to make sense, considering operation precedence.

Comment: You can prove it trying backwards: `echo $x(5)++(6) + ++(7)(5+7=12)$x(7);`

Comment: Read now @Alan machado

Answer (score 1):

See notes in comments

```
$x = 5; 
echo $x . PHP_EOL;
// now x=5

echo ++$x + $x . PHP_EOL;
// left side of the operation makes x=6 then the right side adds x to it, meaning 6+6

echo ++$x . PHP_EOL;
// now x=7
```

Also check this [What's the difference between ++$i and $i++ in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756015/whats-the-difference-between-i-and-i-in-php)
to get some idea about pre vs. post incrementation.

Comment: It's not ++$x+$x.  His is $x+++$x++ which prints 11

Comment: you are right, in OP's form the result is 11. As I wrote it, gives 12. It's just an example on how to use incrementation.

Comment: He's explaining the logic of precedence.

Comment: But it still doesn't solve op's doubt about $x+++$x++

Answer (score 0):

$x ++ means the current value of x is 5, and immediately after that, x will be 6.

for the second x, x = 6, then immediately after that, x = 7.