# use ++a as return, why this happen?

Tags: php, static, operators

recently I did a test on return reference function follow the official example 
 [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php#80776) , but confused with the result when return '++$a' instead, it seems they should be same from the answer [What's the difference between ++$i and $i++ in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756015/whats-the-difference-between-i-and-i-in-php) It seems related to the version of PHP.

#### php version

```
PHP 5.6.28 (cli) (built: Dec  6 2016 12:38:54)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

#### code

```
function &fun(){
        static $var = 1;
        return ++$var;
}

function &bar() {
    static $var = 1;
    ++$var;
    return $var;
}

$var2 =& fun();
$var3 =& bar();
fun();
bar();

echo 'var2:', $var2; // 2  why is it 2 instead of 3?
echo 'var3:', $var3; // 3
```

Comment: @Fky You linked to the wrong "static".  You want static variable scope

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static

Comment: @GordonM Whoops sorry, my mistake

Comment: @Condorcho yeah, I have seen this, I am just confused with 
`return ++$var
// why different result?
++$var; 
return $var`

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `reference` to the same variable. So when you run `bar()` your `$var` is already 2.

Comment: The scope of $var is inside function, it is ok to replace $var with any other names

Answer (score -1):

```
function &fun(){
        static $var = 1;
        return ++$var;
}
```

this function makes very little sense, because its `return` expression contains a value as the operand. The value is being returned after evaluating the unary prefix operator `++`.

So, `++$var` increments a variable, then returns *a value* of the variable, not a reference to a variable itself.

In short: references can be only obtained for a variables, taking a reference from a value does not make much sense.

Comment: from php manual [Incrementing/Decrementing Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php), `++$a, Increments $a by one, then returns $a.` why do you say that returns a _value_ of the variable.

Comment: @RichardLi because in php expressions returns values. File a bug so that they clarified that in the documentation, it clearly must be improved to avoid misunderstanding.