# Why while loop is showing 2 different outputs?

Tags: php, while-loop

Why is while loop showing 2 different outputs?

```
      $a=1;
    while ($a++ <4) {
       echo $a. "<br>";

    }  // output is 2 3 4 but (4 is not less than 4 )



      $a=1;
    while (++$a <4) {
       echo $a. "<br>";

    }       // output is  2 3
```

Please, can someone explain me the difference in detail?
in $a++ it is showing output 2 3 4 but 4 is not less than 4 in while condition then why it is showing 4 which is not satisfying the condition?

Comment: your answer is here all explain why this work like : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9901848/7657988

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between ++$i and $i++ in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756015/whats-the-difference-between-i-and-i-in-php)

Comment: Read effect of pre-increment and post-increment operators here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

Comment: @Rohan     It is effect of  pre-increment and post-increment operators.

Comment: Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simple anwer, when ++ use as suffix, php first execute while, then add 1 number to $a, Meaning in first while your start $i is 1.

And when ++ use as prefix, php first add 1 number to $a, then execute while, Meaning last while your start is 2.

This is same your code:

```
$a=1;
while ($a++ <4) {
   echo $a. "<br>";

}  // output is 2 3 4 but (4 is not less than 4 )
$a++;



$a=1;
$a++;
while (++$a <4) {
   echo $a. "<br>";

}       // output is  2 3
```

Comment: It means that first $a++ store 1 and then increments to 2 after while loop execute and echo value 2

Answer (score 0):

- `++$a` increases value **before** execute
- `$a++` increases value **after** execute