# Why is addition not working instead of increment operator in for loop in PHP?

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, increment, operator-keyword

I needed to increment the for loop by 7 by 7 and used the `$x + 7` method as below. However, it didn't work.

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 31; $x + 7) { 
    echo $x ."\n";
}
```

I solved the problem by redefining the variable as below but I am still wondering why the first method is not working.

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 31; $x += 7) { 
    echo $x ."\n";
}
```

I usually use the `$x++` method to increase the value. Why is `$x + 7` different?

You can try: https://glot.io/snippets/g16a4it4il

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$x + 7` does not alter `x`. It simply evaluates to 7 more than `$x`. To add 7 to `$x`, you can either:

`$x += 7`

or

`$x = $x + 7`

`$x++` increments `$x` by 1. It is roughly equivalent to `$x = $x + 1` or `$x += 1`. (Although when used in an expression, `$x++` evaluates to the value of `$x` *before* the increment happens; for further information see [What's the difference between ++$i and $i++ in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756015/whats-the-difference-between-i-and-i-in-php))

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop works by changing `$x` every iteration until `$x <= 31` is no longer `true`.

`$x + 7` doesn't change `$x`, so it'll always remain `1`